# keep open network folders in windows explorer after disconnect

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, windows-explorer

When a network connection is interrupted, windows explorer silently closes an open network folder. (It changes to "My computer")

The network share is frequently unavailable for short periods, due to the need to switch between corporate VPNs, WIFI access points, notebook going to sleep, etc.

Whenever a network folder becomes temporarily unavoidable due to such a swithc, explorer closes it and I have to re-navigate to the same subdirectory again.

Can I keep that folder open in explorer even when the network connection is lost? It is fine if the files are not available. I just want the explorer window to stay in the unavailable directory, not change to a different one.

The network share contains literally millions of folders, and I use a different one every other day, so caching all files or creating shortcuts to all folders is not practical.

Comment: What you probably want is something that replicates what e.g. Dropbox does for the folders you want to keep syncronized. On Linux tools like `rsync` can do this easily; and then there also exists owncloud.

Comment: no, that is not what i want, i will try to clarify my question: I am fine with not being able to access the files until the connection is restored. I just want explorer to keep the folder window open, even if the files are temporary unavailable. Repeatedly navigating to a sub-sub-sub folder gets annoying very quickly.

Comment: You could try FileZilla. One of its many capabilities is opening network shares and it handles dropped or interrupted connections to filesystems much better. Drag&Drop and anything else you would expect from a file explorer works as well.

Comment: I have the same problem as probably all Windows users who use networks. I assume Microsoft developpers do not use Windows oversiwe they would have corrected it. That's the only explanation I can figure out. I work in a big corporate company without the ability to install some alternative. I hope I will become the boss some day and eject this whole crap.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep network folders open when disconnected as far as I know but you should be able to quickly get back to the folder once reconnected by simply pressing the back button (or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Same over here! This issue has not been solved for years now! In a professional environment with a file server all employees store there work at and with several directories (=projects) open, this causes a lot of work every day. And sometimes the 'back' feature does not work at all.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1151610)